# Control M specific job status to a excel

Tags: linux, suse, control-m, service-control-manager

I have configured control-m batches to execute complex job/workflows.
Is there a way to get the specific job/workflow status to a excel or csv ?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want a daily report made on csv? Can you not run a task every x hours/days/months that would extract the status and insert them on a file?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @fr3nchN. What I need is what are the failed jobs and what are the successfully completed jobs. Like sending the report at a given time. Is that possible? If so how ? :)

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the `ctmlog listmsg` Control-M utility.
This utility needs to be run on the server that hosts the control-m server.

I run the following powershell daily to extract all failures to a text file.
You could do the same for ended OK jobs - just change the message number from 5134 to 5133.

```
#Get Today's and Yesterday's date
$date = Get-Date -Format 'yyyyMMdd'
$m1Date = (get-date).AddDays(-1).ToString('yyyyMMdd')

#Generate and execute Control-M Utility command
$cmd = "ctmlog listmsg 5134 $m1Date 0000 $date 0000 C:\Temp\Todays_Failures.txt"
iex $cmd
```